# Asp.Net Identity lockout end date default time not being set

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Trying to set the default lockout time in MVC 5 to 15 minutes but the timespan being set in the MySql database is for 5 hours after the lockout occurs. What's up with that?

```
        manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
        manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
        manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you probably found the answer already, but this might help others in the future.

The LockOutEndDate saved in the database is UTC time, as the name of the column stands out `LockoutEndDateUtc`. So you are probably living in a zone that has a timezone offset of -05:00.